# Angular 5 - data not binding after redirect

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I have problem with data binding while I am redirecting from one view to another. I am filling the form data in "http://localhost:4200/create" view and then redirecting to "http://localhost:4200/settle/9ed5509c-ecd6-4895-96eb-a2efa04bae6d" (url with token). Nothing is binded correctly after redirection (no binding made at all) but I click refresh (ctrl+r on chrome) then biding is made properly.

create.component.ts

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.model.token = UUID.UUID();

    this.settleService
      .addSettle(this.model)
      .subscribe(settle => this.settles.push(settle));

    this.router
      .navigate([`settle`, this.model.token])
      .then(() => console.log(`Redirection to settle details made!`));

    this.submitted = true;
  }
```

settle.component.ts - ngOnInit() method

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSettle();
    this.currentUrl = window.location.href;
    this.show = false;
  }
```

settle.component.ts - getSettle() method

```
  getSettle(): void {
    const token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.settleService
      .getSettle(token)
      .subscribe(settle => this.settle = settle, null, () => this.BindEditUrl());
  }
```

Comment: Putting a `console.log(settle)` into the subscription of `this.settleService.getSettle(token).subscribe(...)`, what is the output? Does settle have a value?

Comment: With your little help I figure it out, thanks ;)

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figure it out. Mistake was simple - redirection was made before getting response from backend (HTTP POST create settle). I put redirect logic after backend response and everything works now.

Working code:

create.component.ts - onSubmit() method

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.model.token = UUID.UUID();

    this.settleService
      .addSettle(this.model)
      .subscribe(settle => this.settles.push(settle), null, () => this.redirectToSettleDetails());

    this.submitted = true;
  }
```

create.component.ts - redirectToSettleDetails() method

```
  redirectToSettleDetails(): void {
    this.router
      .navigate([`settle`, this.model.token])
      .then(() => console.log(`Redirection to settle details made!`));
  }
```